# Apollo-Angular with Subscription: template not picking up the changes from the subscription

Tags: angularjs, graphql-js, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I am using `apollo-angular` + `subscriptions-transport-ws` in my project. I have the client setup to listen to the subscription for user's password updated or new user is created event. This is how it is setup

```
//Apollo Subscription
this.apollo.subscribe({
  query: this.passwordUpdatedSubscription
}).subscribe(({passwordUpdated}:any) => {
  return this.userDataQuery.updateQuery((previousResult) => {
    let userIndex = previousResult.getUsers.findIndex(user => user.name === passwordUpdated.name);
    let updatedUsers;
    if (userIndex === -1) {
      updatedUsers = [].concat(previousResult.getUsers).concat([passwordUpdated]);

    } else {
      updatedUsers = [].concat(previousResult.getUsers.slice(0, userIndex)).concat([passwordUpdated]);
      if (userIndex !== previousResult.getUsers.length - 1) {
        updatedUsers = updatedUsers.concat(previousResult.getUsers.slice(userIndex + 1));
      }

    }
    return Object.assign({}, previousResult, {
      getUsers: updatedUsers,
    });
  });

});
```

It seems to be working fine and does its job to notify the `userDataQuery` about the update. In the `userDataQuery`, it handles the updates this way

```
this.userDataQuery = this.apollo.watchQuery({
  query: this.getUsersQuery
}).subscribe(({data}:any) => {
  this.userData = data.getUsers;
  // I have to call detectChanges to tell Angular to re-render the template.
  // is there anyway to avoid doing this?
  //this.ref.detectChanges();

});
```

The userData did get updated successfully, However, the changes is not reflected on the template. I will have to call `this.ref.detectChanges();` to update the template.

The template is very simple

```
<span ng-if="userData">{{userData && userData[0] && userData[0].password}}    </span>
```

Is there anything I am missing in the code. I thought the template should pick up the change automatically ?